# My language dropdown doesn't work when searching with apostrophe in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, search, catalogsearch, language-package

Please see the screenshot:

First 1:https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1SNR.png

Second 2:https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKcci.png

Comment: The JSON data is not correct ... See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656389/json-parse-error-unterminated-string

Comment: I know this is the Json validation error but how to fix in magento 2